# Wordpress selectively applying css rules following wp_enqueue_style

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm in the process of transferring an HTML/CSS/jquery mockup of a website into a wordpress theme. The site runs perfectly as an HTML site and all of the css rules are selecting the correct html elements.

However, when I enqueue the scripts to Wordpress and look at the site, only certain rules are being applied, resulting in the website having a broken look. I know the css is being correctly enqueued since I can see it showing up in the page source for the website. When I look at specific elements with web inspector it shows that only certain rules are being implemented but not others. Why would transferring my css to Wordpress change how the css rules apply to almost identical HTML?

Below the code for how I'm enqueuing scripts. Note the dependency on normalize:

```
<?php

//
function theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'normalize' ) );
}


// Load the theme JS
function theme_js() {

    wp_register_script('stickynav',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/stickynav.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_register_script('nouislider',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/nouislider.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_register_script('bootstrap2',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap2.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_register_script('foundation',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_register_script('orbit',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.orbit.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_register_script('modernizr',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.custom.49510.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('stickynav');
    wp_enqueue_script('nouislider');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap2');
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr');
    wp_enqueue_script('theme_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

    if (is_home() && !is_paged() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('foundation');
        wp_enqueue_script('orbit');
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_styles');

// Enable custom menus
add_theme_support ('menus');

?>
```

This is the html/php I have in header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            <?php

                wp_title( '-', true, 'right' );

                bloginfo('name');

            ?>
        </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div  id="header_top_wrapper">

          <!-- header and subheader -->
          <div class="row" id="header-top">
              <div class="large-12 columns" id="my_logo">
                  <a href ="<?php bloginfo( 'siteurl'); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name'); ?></a>
              </div>
              <div class="large-6 columns large-uncentered" id="subheader">
                <a href ="<?php bloginfo( 'siteurl'); ?>"><h4><?php bloginfo( 'description'); ?></h4></a>
              </div>
          </div>

          <!-- sticky navigation bar -->
          <div id="sticky_navigation_wrapper">
            <div id="sticky_navigation">
              <div class="navigation_items">
                  <li class="nav-left"><a href="#">HOUSEPLANS.INFO</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-left"><a href="#search_modal" data-toggle="modal">SEARCH PLANS</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-left"><a href="#">MOST VIEWED</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-right"><a  href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-right" id="site-search">
                    <form action="/search" method="get">
                      <input type="text" name="s" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search";>
                      <i class="icon-search"></i>
                    </form>
                  </li>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

  </div><!-- end #header_top_wrapper -->
```

As an example of the selective application, these are the rules that are being applied to a link nested inside of an list item li on the HTML mockup

```
#sticky_navigation ul li a {
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 5px;
height: 36px;
padding: 0;
line-height: 36px;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
color: white;
}

#sticky_navigation ul {
list-style: none;
}

body {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
}
```

And this is what is being applied to the same link in the Wordpress version of the same HTML and CSS

```
a {
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: inherit;
}

li {
text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

body {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Below is the CSS style for the area in question:

```
/* Logo and subheader */

#my_logo { 
  font:45px Georgia, Times, serif;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

#subheader h4{
  margin: 6px 0 0 0;
}


/* our menu styles */
#sticky_navigation_wrapper { 
  width:100%; 
  height:36px;
}

#sticky_navigation { 
  width:100%;
  height:36px;
  /* background: rgba(65, 105,255,.4); */
  background: black;
  z-index: 1030;
}

.navigation_items { 
  width:960px; 
  margin:0 auto;
}

.navigation_items ul{
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navigation_items ul.pull-left:after {
  clear: both;
}

#sticky_navigation ul { 
  list-style:none; 
  margin: 0;
  /* padding:0; */
}

#sticky_navigation ul li{ 
  margin:0;
  display:inline-block;
}
#sticky_navigation ul li a{ 
  /* float:left; */
  /*margin:0 0 0 5px;*/
  height:36px;
  /* padding: 0; */
  line-height:36px; 
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:normal; 
  color:white;
}

.nav-left{
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.nav-right {
  float: right !important;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

What is going on here? I've been up all night trying to figure this out. 
I'm enqueuing correctly, and according to the page source the exact same css is in the header as in my non-Wordpress version.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_styles');
```

But probably you should change it to:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_style','theme_styles');
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_styles');
```

to

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_style','theme_styles');
```

Also please remember that if you change or edit the css, you need to delete your cache and your visitors also needs to delete their browser's cache. But of course there's a better way to do it. Just fill in the "version" arguments on the wp_enqueue_style.

Do it like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_style','theme_styles', array(), '1.0.0');
```

Every time you edit your css. Just change the version to '1.0.1' or '1.0.2' and so on. This will force your visitor's browser to get the latest version of the css.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

UL tags were missing for the li's - somehow deleted while inserting PHP.

DOH!